# Self type and collections

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

If I want to have a `Self` type in C++, I usually resort to CRTP:

```
template<class Self> struct Base {
    auto self() -> Self* { return static_cast<Self*>(this); }
};
struct Derived : public Base<Derived> {};

void fn() {
    Derived d;
    Derived *p = d.self();
}
```

But this won't work if I want a collection of `Base`s:

```
std::vector<Base<???>*> bases; // <- No useful `Self` parameter here
```

Is there a way in C++17/C++20 to get a `Self` type such that the `Base` can still be used in containers?
I don't want to override `self()` in every child class and I don't want `dynamic_cast`s.

---

As a small example where `Self` types come in handy, consider an `ICopy` interface.

```
class ICopy {
public:
  virtual ~ICopy() = default;
  virtual auto copy() const -> Self = 0; // Self is not known to C++, but other languages know it
};
```

Comment: Feels like an XY problem. Why is `self` even needed?

Comment: The good news is that it's built-in. Just put a base class pointer in the containers. You don't need `dynamic_cast`s either if you declare `virtual` methods in the base class.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I want a fluent API to change properties of objects deriving `Base`. For example `obj->rotate(...)->scale(...)` and I don't want to lose the actual type of `obj` in the process

Comment: So, polymorphism? `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<CommonBase>>`

Comment: Let's pretend `std::vector<Base<???>> bases;` magically worked, and we could store any derived class in the vector. What would be the type of `bases[0].self()` ? Isn't that something that can only be known at runtime?

Comment: "But this won't work if I want a collection of Bases:" ... I don't understand where this would work. What is `Self` ? Is it supposed to be `T` ?

Comment: if you need lots of casts to the derived type then very likely you are doing polymorphism without polymorphism. The typical solution is to redesign so that you do not need the casts, or not use polymorphism in the first place

Comment: @chi Oh yeah, I mistyped that in the question and will correct it. It should of course be an `std::vector<Base<???>*>`, otherwise I could not fill the vector with children anyway ;) The type of `bases[0].self()` would ideally be `Base` itself (which of course doesn't work, because the template needs to be instantiated)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number For every derived class `C`, `Self` is exactly `C`. This is a normal feature in other languages, for example, Rust has `Self` types. They are used when the return type of a method is the class itself (for example a `Copy` trait/interface would return `Self`)

Comment: makes sense if `Self == T`. if not, I dont understand what `T` is good for

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Since C++ does not support `Self` types as a language feature, you use curiously recurring templates for this.

Comment: @Proof-By-Sledgehammer by now I understand that it is CRTP. All I am saying is that there is a typo in your CRTP. `T` should be `Self`.

Comment: don't get me wrong, but an issue with the question is that you are asking for a language feature that C++ doesn't have. Though C++ has different features to solve the same problems that in other languages you can solve with `Self`. Concerning your concrete example: crtp is about static polymorphism, `std::vector< something Base>` is about dynamic polymorphism. crtp doesn't help for dynamic polymorphism (though I do understand what you want to get at, and I guess that you are already aware that crtp doesn't help to get there)

Comment: For your `ICopy` example, derived types are allowed to have overridden virtual functions return a derived type. So you can have `struct Derived : ICopy { virtual Derived* copy() const override { ... }};` No need for a self.

Comment: This is question is just all mixed up. The `Self` type in Rust is just the static type of some "thing" which is contextually determined in the source code (e.g. the object for a member function). Likewise in C++ we always have the static type. `Self` is a convenience. There are small differences in details (it's implicit in Rust trait definitions, explicit in C++ concept definitions), but `Self` doesn't let you do any of the things you seem to want to do.

Comment: To put things satisfying a common trait/concept in a container you need type erasure (`dyn` in Rust, always hand-rolled in C++). I suspect that's what you really want? These things interact in the way you expect in both Rust and C++. When you act on an erased type, you get that erased type back. If you want to share a particular implementation of some concept, that's what CRTP does. So yes, you can use your CRTP base to define a `self()` but once you erase it, `self()` will return the erased type.

Comment: To have the static return type depend on the dynamic type of the input, i.e. runtime data, is a form of dependent typing and neither C++ nor Rust have that in a helpful way.
For `ICopy` in particular, you want a signature which includes the input object type, so use CRTP if you have an implementation to share, or use free template functions if you want to call implementations that others will write.

Comment: Free template functions are less "fluent" of course, but you can overload operators like in `std::ranges` to regain some of that. In C++23, we'll get deducing this, and that will make CRTP easier. It will still dispatch based on the static type though. Basically, your wants are at odds, you want to put objects in a homogeneous container (same type) but also operate on them "preserving the type" (different types).